# Getting JSONObject from JSONObject parent

Tags: java, android, json

All I am getting resources are getting `JSONObject` from `JSONArray`.  But in this case, I want to get the temperature which is "temp". I don't think it is part of an array. How can I get that?

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":85.17,
      "lat":26.67
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":500,
         "main":"Rain",
         "description":"light rain",
         "icon":"10d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":31.09,
      "pressure":1004.15,
      "humidity":83,
      "temp_min":31.09,
      "temp_max":31.09,
      "sea_level":1010.39,
      "grnd_level":1004.15
   },
   "wind":{  
      "speed":3.66,
      "deg":107.5
   },
   "rain":{  
      "3h":0.202
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":64
   },
   "dt":1534148929,
   "sys":{  
      "message":0.0048,
      "country":"IN",
      "sunrise":1534117810,
      "sunset":1534165068
   },
   "id":1273043,
   "name":"Dhaka",
   "cod":200
}
```

I have tried- (I am new with JSON)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
JSONObject temp = main.getJSONObject("temp");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Android (tagging appropriately helps here, as it depends on the JSON library you're using):

Since you've got `JSONObject main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");`, you should then just be able to do `double temp = main.getDouble("temp");` to get the temperature off that `main` object.

If you have a look at the [docs for JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) you can see a variety of methods for getting JSON "primitive" fields, such as `int`, `String`, etc. - and you need to use those to retrieve said primitive fields, rather than calling `getJSONObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from `main` object using "temp" as key

```
double temp = main.getDouble("temp");
```

Answer (score 0):

temp is not a JSonObject. you can get the temperature as String or double. So change the last line of your code with:

```
String temp = main.getString("temp");
```

or

```
double temp = main.getDouble("temp");
```