# How to get JsonValueKind from JsonObject?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have JsonObject that is created like this:

`JsonObject jsonObj = JsonNode.Parse(inputString).AsObject();`

I then get property value from it like this

```
if (jsonObj.TryGetPropertyValue("property1", out JsonNode? property))
{
   var myProp = property.GetValue<string>();
}
```

Is there a way to lookup ValueKind of that property?

`property.ValueKind` is not working.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819153/getting-jsonobject-from-jsonobject-parent) there is an example with ValueKind, but it's getting it from JsonDocument.RootElement, but not from JsonObject:

```
...
using JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString, documentOptions);

JsonElement root = document.RootElement;

if (root.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
{
...
```

And there is no RootElement for JsonNode or JsonObject.

Is there a way to get ValueKind from JsonObject? I can see in VisualStudio that it is there embedded in the Value:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: For what you expected, you want to loop each property in the `json` object and get its `ValueKind`?

Comment: The `JsonValueKind` for a `JsonObject` will always be `JsonValueKind.Object`.  Now if you have a `JsonValue` and need to get the `ValueKind`, see [How to find out what type a JsonValue is in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71587944).  (Honestly it's harder than it should be.)

Comment: Additionally, `JsonNodeExtensions.GetValueKind(this JsonNode node, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)` from [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827#issuecomment-889443545) by [steveharter](https://github.com/steveharter) to [JsonNode feedback #55827](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827) seems to do what you need.  (Be sure to click on *`click for samples`* to see the code.)